# Define concat function for Digits

Tags: haskell

I have a list chars and I would like to concat all characters, which are digits and which are next to each other

For example: `['1','5','+','2','4'] => ["15","+","24"]`

```
concat1 :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [String]
concat1 [] [] = []
concat1 [a] [b]
    | (isDigit a) && (isDigit b) = [a] ++ [b]
```

I tried to write this code, but it doesn't seem to be right approach and debugger tells me this:

```
Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: [String]
        Actual type: [Char]
    * In the expression: [a] ++ [b]
      In an equation for `concat1':
          concat1 [a] [b] | (isDigit a) && (isDigit b) = [a] ++ [b]
```

Comment: leading question - what is the type of `a` and `b` in `concat1 [a] [b] = ...`? What is the type of `[a]`? `[b]`? `[a] ++ [b]`?

Comment: They are both chars in a list, aren't they?

Comment: It's helpful when getting started to have a mechanism for writing this down, so you can work through errors like this. Just as you wrote that `concat1` has type `[Char] -> [Char] -> [String]` using `::`, write down the type of `a`, `b`, `[a]`, `[b]`, and `[a] ++ [b]`.

Comment: This doesn't address your misunderstandings at all, but: ```groupBy ((==) `on` isDigit)```. Might be worth trying to reimplement each of those pieces yourself if you're not sure how that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `concat1` is wrong: your example indicates you want *one* input list and an output list. The input list (ex: `['1','5','+','2','4']`) is of type `[Char]` and the output (ex: `["15","+","24"]`) of type `[String]`. That gives the signature

```
concat1 :: [Char] -> [String]
```

For the implementation, you probably want to use [`span`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:span), which finds the prefix satisfying a certain predicate function and also returns the remaining elements.

```
concat1 [] = []
concat1 (e : es)
  | isDigit e = let (d, es') = span isDigit (e : es) in d : concat1 es'
  | otherwise = [ e ] : concat1 es
```

Then, trying it out at GHCi:

```
ghci> concat1 ['1','5','+','2','4']
["15","+","24"]
```

Answer (score 2):

An idea might be to construct a more generic function: a `groupWith :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [(b,[a])]` function like the one that is defined in Python's `itertools`:

```
groupWith :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [(b,[a])]
groupWith f = steps . map ((,) =<< f)
    where steps [] = []
          steps ((b,a):xs) = (b,(a : map snd ys)) : steps zs
              where (ys,zs) = span ((b == ) . fst) xs
```

Given a function `f :: a -> b` and a list `xs`, it will construct groups `[(b,[a])]` such that every group represents the longest possible sequence of `xs` where `f x` is the same. So for `groupWith isDigit "15+24"`, we get:

```
*Main Data.Char> groupWith isDigit ['1','5','+','2','4']
[(True,"15"),(False,"+"),(True,"24")]
```

Now we can simply obtain the second element `snd` of every tuple, so:

```
*Main Data.Char> map snd $ groupWith isDigit ['1','5','+','2','4']
["15","+","24"]
```

We can easily reuse this piece of code if we for instance wish to discriminate based on more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) in order to group together adjacent elements in a list over some equivalence function. You can use is like this:

```
import Data.List (groupBy)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Char (isDigit)

groupDigits :: String -> [String]
groupDigits = groupBy ((&&) `on` isDigit)
```

---

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Function Data.Char> groupDigits ['1','5','+','2','4']
["15","+","24"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess as @4castle mentioned `groupBy` is the ideal tool for this job however my approach would be slightly different.

```
import Data.List (groupBy)
import Data.Function (on)

groupDigits :: String -> [String]
groupDigits = groupBy ((==) `on` ((&&) <$> (>'/') <*> (<':')))

*Main> groupDigits ['1','5','+','2','4'] 
["15","+","24"]
*Main> groupDigits ['1','5','+','+','2','4'] 
["15","++","24"]
```

The difference is instead of using `(&&)` operator i use an XNOR (which is simply `(==)` in Haskell).

And also my implementation of `isDigit :: Char -> Bool` is a little different than it is in `Data.Char`.